# asp net Identity 2.0 beta1 with extended Guid Primary Key EF Migrations issue

Tags: identity, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP Net Identity 2.0 beta1 and followed the instructions on:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/20/announcing-preview-of-microsoft-aspnet-identity-2-0-0-alpha1.aspx
to extend the Primary Key to be a GUID instead of the standard string. I had to do this for foreign keys to work with existing tables. Using Code First.

I do not have any extra code in my db context OnModelCreating.

The issue I'm having, is when trying to Add-Migration I get the error:

> MyApp.Business.GuidUserLogin: : EntityType 'GuidUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> MyApp.Business.GuidUserRole: : EntityType 'GuidUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>
> GuidUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'GuidUserLogins' is based on type 'GuidUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
>
> GuidUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'GuidUserRoles' is based on type 'GuidUserRole' that has no keys defined.

Answer (score 1):

The fix was to manually add the keys in the DbContext under the OnModelCreating override:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
        modelBuilder.Entity<GuidUserRole>().HasKey( x=> new {
            x.RoleId,
            x.UserId
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<GuidUserLogin>().HasKey(x => new
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.ProviderKey,
            x.LoginProvider
        });
}
```

After this addition the ef migrations worked fine and I was able to create users roles etc.